# write function to replace variable with itself plus 1% of its median

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm new to writing functions in R, but want to write a function to add 1% of the median of a variable to itself, using dplyr, and replace the variable with this transformation.

x is a numeric variable.

```
add_median <- function(df, x) {
  x <- enquo(x)
  x <- quo_name(x)
  mutate(x=x+.01*median(x, na.rm=T)) 
  }
```

When I run `newDF <- DF %>% add_median(variable_of_interest)`, I get the following error:

**Error in 0.01 * median(x, na.rm = T) : non-numeric argument to binary operator**

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could change the function to evaluate with `{{}}` and then use assign (`:=`) instead of `=` in `mutate`

```
library(dplyr)
add_median <- function(df, x) {
         df %>%
              mutate({{x}} := {{x}} + .01 * median({{x}}, na.rm = TRUE))
 }
```

If we need to change multiple columns, use `mutate_at`

```
add_median_multiple <- function(df, vec){
    df %>%
         mutate_at(vars(vec), ~ . + .01 * median(., na.rm = TRUE))
  }
```

-testing

```
data(mtcars)
head(mtcars) %>%
     add_median(mpg)
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.21   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.21   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        23.01   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.61   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.91   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.31   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

comparison with original 'mpg' column

```
head(mtcars)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

---

```
add_median_multiple(head(mtcars), c('mpg', 'wt'))
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat      wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#Mazda RX4         21.21   6  160 110 3.90 2.65045 16.46  0  1    4    4
#Mazda RX4 Wag     21.21   6  160 110 3.90 2.90545 17.02  0  1    4    4
#Datsun 710        23.01   4  108  93 3.85 2.35045 18.61  1  1    4    1
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.61   6  258 110 3.08 3.24545 19.44  1  0    3    1
#Hornet Sportabout 18.91   8  360 175 3.15 3.47045 17.02  0  0    3    2
#Valiant           18.31   6  225 105 2.76 3.49045 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: thank you! this works perfectly - do you mind walking me through what the double brackets {{}}  and assign operator  (:=) actually do here, and why they are needed? or pointing me to a good resource for this?

Comment: @MS_714 The `{{}}` does the `enquo` + `!!` (evaluation).  the `{{}}` on the `lhs` of `:=` evaluate to return the name of the variable instead of the value and does the assignment

Comment: @MS_714 it is better to check the llatest vignettes from tidyverse to understand the current functions and its behavior

Comment: thanks @akrun. i can't get this function to run on more than one column. is there a way to code it so it's possible to specify more than one column?

Comment: @MS_714 You can change it to `mutate_at` and then pass a vector of column names as string